# changing hive data base to mysql

Tags: hive

I'm not getting any error in any step but after creation of the tables in Hive ,when i'm trying to querying in mysql (show tables), its showing empty result(Empty set (0.00 sec)).

```
         <configuration>
            <property>
                  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
                   <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore_db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
<description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description>
            </property>

            <property>
             <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
             <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
              <description>MySQL JDBC driver class</description>
            </property>

            <property>
              <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
              <value>hiveuser</value>
              <description>user name for connecting to mysql server </description>
            </property>

            <property>
             <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
             <value>hivepassword</value>
             <description>password for connecting to mysql server                  </description>
            </property>

             <property>
             <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
             <value>thrift://localhost:9083</value>
             </property>
```

Answer (score 0):

First run

```
mysql -u hiveuser
show databases
use metastore_db
show tables
```

Are you able to create tables in hive?

Do you find logs like this?

```
[root@sandbox ~]# cd /var/log/hive
[root@sandbox hive]# ls -ltr *.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 hive hadoop    1255 2015-11-02 23:54 hive.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 hive hadoop    1255 2015-11-02 23:54 hive-server2.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 hive hadoop  179943 2015-12-08 10:28 hivemetastore.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 hive hadoop 1738852 2015-12-08 10:34 hiveserver2.log
[root@sandbox hive]#
```

Comment: I have run mysql server but no database is created in mysql but i am able to create tables in hive. I place mysql connector in hive/lib directory. I think hive stil using derby database where ever i am running hive it creating metastore_db in that path.

Comment: Have you restarted hive metastore server after making changes to hive-site.xml?

Comment: i dint restart when i am restarting its taking so much time for that

Comment: You need to check the logs to see where it is struck.

Comment: log files means the files which are there in /tmp/hive rit??

Comment: No, you need to check logs under /var/log. Are you using any distribution or plain vanilla? /tmp/hive is to store logs for individual queries and sessions not for installation. Installation logs will be typically under /var/log. You can try running find /var/log -name "*.log"|xargs grep -i hive

Comment: I am new to  hadoop i installed hadoop by using centos .. I wil check with those logs . Thank u so much for ur rply. when i type hadoop version its showing Compiled by hortonfo on Wed Oct  3 05:13:58 UTC 2012 means it using horton distribution???

Comment: Not necessarily. Most likely you are using plain vanilla hadoop. Go through the hive server installation logs and see where the issue is.

Comment: i am not able to find log files can u please tel where that default directory wil be there

Comment: in var/log i dint find any hive related log files ?? can u pls hlp me this out

Comment: Do you have /var/log/hive directory or not? If yes, you should see the output like the one in the answer above.

Comment: [root@sandbox ~]# cd /var/log/hive
[root@sandbox hive]# ls -ltr *.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 hive hadoop    1255 2015-11-02 23:54 hive.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 hive hadoop    1255 2015-11-02 23:54 hive-server2.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 hive hadoop  179943 2015-12-08 10:28 hivemetastore.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 hive hadoop 1738852 2015-12-08 10:34 hiveserver2.log
[root@sandbox hive]#

Comment: hi i dont have var/log/hive file

Comment: I am not sure then, some where it will have the log files. Unless you go to it, it will be tough to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: when i extract the hive tar bar in hive/conf directory i have hive-default.xml when i'm trying to change to mysql as hive db i have to create hive-site.xml or its k to edit the changes in hive-default.cml